# Symmetry of a distribution

Tags: distributions, mean, median, mode

I have received a sample, summarized by a frequency table with groups (i.e. 1-7, 7-10, 10-13, 13-16, etc...)

I calculated the mean and median, both were around 15, the mean was 15.3, the median 15.6. The mode was 18. I have calculated the mean by using the middle point of each interval. The median was calculated using an histogram (there is also an identical formula, the one with L0 and L1 if you know which one I mean). The mode was calculated as the middle point of the group with the highest density.

I need to say if this distribution is symmetric, symmetric with a bell curve, or not of the options. The first group is wider, and thus in the histogram, it looks only approximately symmetric, and not bell shaped. It looks a bit like left-skewed but just a bit.

Is there a rule for the situation where mean=median smaller than mode ?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, it should have the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Because a mode is arbitrary--its calculation depends on how the data are grouped--and, when used to infer the mode of a population, can be very uncertain--the mode is of little use in assessing symmetries. Instead use the mid-quantiles, defined as the averages of complementary quantiles (such as the average of the upper and lower quartiles). A plot of the mid-quantiles will be perfectly constant for symmetric distributions; deviations from a constant indicate (and measure) departures from symmetry. Because "bell curve" is too vague to be of any quantitative use, that issue cannot be addressed.